# Sorting HTML String in PHP

Tags: php

I have a srting which is coming through loop

```
<li class=" mega-group "><a target="_self" ><span class="menu-title">Alloys</span></a></li>
<li class=" mega-group "><a target="_self" ><span class="menu-title">cla</span></a></li>
<li class=" mega-group "><a target="_self" ><span class="menu-title">blloys</span></a></li>
<li class=" mega-group "><a target="_self" ><span class="menu-title">zloys</span></a></li>
```

This is my actual HTML which is coming using PHP Logic. it is showing out at

```
Allows
Clas
Blloys
zloys
```

which is ok

But i want sorting like this

```
Allows 
Blloys
Clas
zloys
```

Can anybody tell me how we achieve this result 
Thanks

Comment: You woul;d need to sort your data array you use to create the html .. it would hlep to see the PHP you use.

Comment: You have to order your source data before looping in PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort();` function

```
$arr = array( 'Allows', 'Clas', 'Blloys', 'zloys');

sort($arr);
```

now loop, it will give you result in order

```
foreach($arr as $v) {
    echo '<li class=" mega-group "><a target="_self" ><span class="menu-title">'.$v.'</span></a></li>';
}
```

- Allows
- Blloys
- Clas
- zloys